# Gallerific Jquery Plugin is not working in Google chrome and Firefox after uploading the website but it is working locally

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, firefox, galleriffic

I have been working to a develop a website where I need to show image gallery with slider. Therefore, I have used Gallerific-2.0 jquery image gallery plugin for that. This plugin is working fine locally. However, it is not working after I upload it to the server. 
Here is the link of my website on what I am working now
http://www.mcorporation.us/under_development.html
I have already tried using gallerific.cascading.js from this https://code.google.com/p/galleriffic/issues/detail?id=226 suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

I have re arranged the javascript files as mentioned in the website. Then, mentioned the javascript files in the head of html. Also, re uploaded files to the server. Now, it is working perfectly.